# Spivak, Ch. 18, Problem *46a: Suppose $f\neq 0$ with $f'=f$. Prove that $f(x)\neq 0$ for each $x$. What exactly is being asked here?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-explanation, exponential-function

> *46. This problem, a companion to Problem 15-30, outlines a treatment of the exponential function starting from the assumption that the
> differential equation $f'=f$ has a nonzero solution.
>
> (a) Suppose there is a function $f\neq 0$ with $f'=f$. Prove that
> $f(x)\neq 0$ for each $x$ by considering the function
> $g(x)=f(x_0+x)f(x_0-x)$, where $f(x_0)\neq 0$.

Let me try to understand this.

We assume there is a function such that

1. $f$ is not $0$ for all $x$
2. for any $x$, $f'(x)=f(x)$

And we're supposed to prove that $f(x)\neq 0$ for each $x$.

We also have the assumptions

3. $g(x)=f(x_0+x)f(x_0-x)$
4. $f(x_0)\neq 0$

Then we have

$$g'(x)=f'(x_0+x)f(x_0-x)-f(x_0+x)f'(x_0-x)=0$$

where we used assumption 2. Therefore, $g$ is constant. Using assumption 4,

$$g(0)=[f(x_0)]^2>0$$

Therefore,

$$g(x)=f(x_0+x)f(x_0-x)=c>0$$

Which implies that $\forall x, f(x)\neq 0$.

Seems we proved that if we assume the existence of a non-zero function $f$ satisfying $f'=f$, then we are led to the conclude that actually such a function is not zero anywhere.

Is this the correct interpretation of the question and solution?

Comment: While I haven't read your proof, your interpretation of what is being asked of you is correct.

Comment: Everything is just fine. I leave another question on the same spirit, while having prove that $f(x)\ne 0$ for all $x$, assuming more that $f(x_{0})>0$, prove that $f$ is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation of the question is correct, and the solution is mostly good. The only thing that you might want to do is explicitly state that if $\exists x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1) = 0$ then $g(x_1 - x_0) = 0$ which is a contradiction with the fact that $g(x) > 0 \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.